# Launch Selenium on AWS Lambda 2023

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I've just spent the past 4 days trying to get selenium to work on AWS Lambda. I've been using Selenium for years and now need to integrate AWS into my Selenium tasks but I've had no luck.

I've followed about 5 different tutorials and editing them in various ways once discovering they don't work.

Please some help, i'm gonna lose my mind soon enough

#python #selenium #aws

Tried - Putting chrome driver zip in layer along side putting selenium zipped in another layer

Tried - Putting chrome driver in s3 and linking the driver that way

Tried - Just about everything (save me)

Comment: Does the lambda return anything? Please include that

Comment: When following examples online word for word I get the response "Code is executing". So the code runs and returns no errors however doesn't do anything. So I have to then use throttle to stop the application and try debug again as no errors are returned